# How to set permissions for a specific user in ACL?

Tags: security, permissions, acl, access-control

I'm developing an application, where users are able to store their notes.

The roles hierarchy is the following:

- `user` role could create, read, update and delete their **own**
  notes.
- `admin` role inherits `user` role and has access to
  **all** users notes.

The issue is, that most of ACL tutorials, are describing generic cases, regarding how to declare permissions for a roles like `user`, `admin`, `manager` etc.

There is a lack of information regarding the cases, when we need to protect specific user notes from changing by other users. How to handle this in the scope of ACL?

Comment: I like to do it by assigning a role to the user in the DB and checking against it. Do some research into `authentication` vs. `authorization`. You could use a numerical hierarchy such as level 1, 2, 3 and require that the user has level 2 in order to execute the query (ie: `if (userRole >= 2) { ... }`), or you can make a function such as `requireAdmin()` that proceeds if the user meets the criteria.

Comment: You could check inside the query also if certain fields require elevated privileges: `if (userRole === 'admin') { return result } else { return null }`